# Thrown with message “View [markets.index] not found.”

Tags: php, laravel, terminal, laravel5

Я использую Laravel 5.5, и я начинающий. После запуска моего сервера - я получаю ошибку в браузере, как это

```
throw new InvalidArgumentException("View [$name] not found."); - View [markets.index] not found.
```

Что мне делать? Я видел такие разные вопросы, но эти ответы мне не помогли.

Вот мой index.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Market</title>

</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <?php 

        @foreach ($markets as $market)

        <li>
            <a href = "{{ route('markets.show', $market) }}">
                {{$market->name}}
            </a>
        </li>

        @endforeach

         ?>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте наличие blade шаблона, вот путь от корня проекта `/resources/views/markets/index.blade.php`.

Так как система ругается на отсутствие данного шаблона.

И проверьте роут `markets.show`, там скорее всего прописано `return view('markets.index');` а у вас его нет.

Comment: Извините, я начинающий. Где я могу его посмотреть?

Comment: @DanielKiz обновил пост, от корня проекта откройте папку resources,затем views, там есть папка markets ?

Comment: неа, есть index.blade.php, welcome.blade.php

Comment: просто для примера, создайте папку `markets` в папке `views`, и туда скопируйте свой `index.blade.php` и проблема пропадет, а так вам нужно посмотреть файл `web.php` в папке `routes` (в корне) и там должна быть запись `return view('market.index')`

Comment: Да, спасибо, но вот еще одна `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH) (View: /market/resources/views/markets/index.blade.php)`, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: @DanielKiz, так вы скопировали `index.blade.php` в market, а там у вас есть цикл `foreach($markets ...)`, но `$markets` у вас нет, удалите цикл